# How to remove/clear data stored in scope variables on logout in angularjs app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have four controllers in my angular app. I am storing data in scope variables in all the controllers. I want to clear/remove data of all the scope variables on logout. On logout, I am declaring login id and password as blank but how to clear data of other scope variables of other controllers? I don't want to use route.reload as it gives bad UX.

Answer (score 1):

Well normally you declare variables somewhere and set them back to null when you leave.

$scope is a normal JavaScript object with key values so it should be possible to

```
delete $scope.key;
delete $scope.keyTwo;
```

Comment: Is there any method to clear all scope variable at once?

Comment: Hmm I dont know your code, but if you copy the $scope JSON, after construction of it, and copy it back on logout, this will "clear" your scope...

Comment: Something like var initialScope = $scope; would copy it and when you want to logout, just do a $scope = initialScope; to clear it